# How can I use aggregation in multiple field in view

Tags: views

I want to group by multiple field but I don't know how it works.

In my view, I have :

Code A | cmd Date | Quantity | Price A | Total |

And I want to regroup by *Code A* then regroup by *cmd Date*.

For each CodeA I have multiple order in the same month and I want to regroup them, then sum quantity and total. Like :

|Code1 | 09/2015 | 15 | 5 | 75€ |
|----------|10/2015 | 10 | 5 | 50€ |
|Code2 | 08/2015 | 11 | 7 | 77€ |
|----------|11/2015 | 10 | 7 | 70€ |

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to enable fields in your view. Then in your formatting settings you can now use "group by". You can also use more than one grouping field. Hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks, not exactly the display I wanted but that work.

Edit : If I use the format Table Rowspan with the grouping field and aggregation, is exactly that I want !